# Binomial cumulative distribution function

Tags: probability, limits

Let $X$ be a binomial random variable with parameters (n,p). I want to compute the limit 
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\mathbb{P}(X>n/2)
$$
I know that the cdf of Binomial does not have a basic closed form solution. Intuitively, I think this is 1 for $p>\frac{1}{2}$ and 0 for $p<\frac{1}{2}$. How can I prove this limit?

Comment: Hint : use the central limit theorem.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy Only if $p=\frac12$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strong law of large numbers ensures that $X_n/n\to p$ almost surely hence $\mathbb P(X_n\gt\frac12n)\to0$ if $p\lt\frac12$ and $\mathbb P(X_n\gt\frac12n)\to1$ if $p\gt\frac12$.

If $p=\frac12$, the central limit theorem states that $X_n=\frac12n+\frac12\sqrt{n}Z_n$ where $Z_n$ converges in distribution to a standard normal random variable, hence $\mathbb P(X_n\gt\frac12n)=\mathbb P(Z_n\gt0)\to\frac12$.